# How to avoid escaping double quotes and single quotes in php

Tags: php

I am sure there must be a better way than putting a backslash (`\`) to escape double quotes in php

Suppose i have the following

```
 <param name="flashvars" value="config={clip:{autoPlay:true,autoHide.....
```

The `value` consist of many `"` and `'` and its getting tedious adding `\` before every `"`

Comment: Is this related to PHP or to xml/html attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [heredoc](http://brugbart.com/php-heredoc)

```
$mystring = <<<LOL
<param name="flashvars" value="config={clip:{autoPlay:true,autoHide "double quotes" and 'single quotes',plus $variables too...
LOL;
```

Or simply:

```
echo <<<LOL
<param name="flashvars" value="config={clip:{autoPlay:true,autoHide "double quotes"and 'single quotes', plus $variables too...
LOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) in this case. Don't use it for queries to a database though. Use specific escape functions for that.

```
$param = "config={clip:autoPlay:True,autoHide..."; // put full value here
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="<?php echo addslashes($param) ?>">
```